# Is there a pure CSS way to make an input transparent?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this input transparent?

```
<input type="text" class="foo">
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
background:transparent url(../img/transpSmall.png) repeat scroll 0 0;
```

Comment: Set the input to be the same colour as what is behind it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want input type="hidden"?

Comment: Could be a spam honeypot, which would be a legit use, although having something visible but still focusable isn't a great idea.

Comment: @Rich, then it's not editable...if you've already got the colour for the container set, why would you also want to set it on the input tag?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

Nobody will even know it's there.

Comment: @Metropolis pleased to report that nobody cares about it at 2016

Comment: This breaks in Netscape 1.0 and Zune.

Comment: My potato doesn't support this

Comment: If you want to remove the outline when focused as well try:

    `input[type="text"],
    input[type="text"]:focus
    {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        outline-width: 0;
    }`

Comment: in my case this solution just work in firefox and don't work in chrome.

Comment: add this  `outline: none;` for the shadow on the box when typing

Answer (score 30):

I like to do this

```
input[type="text"]
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Setting the `outline` property to `none` stops the browser from highlighting the box when the cursor enters

Comment: `outline: none` breaks keyboard accessibility. See @derekshirk's answer below.

Answer (score 10):

The two methods previously described are not enough today. I personnally use :

```
input[type="text"]{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width:5px;
    color:transparent;
    cursor:default;
}
```

It also removes the shadow set on some browsers, hide the text that could be input and make the cursor behave as if the input was not there.

You may want to set width to 0px also.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove the outline when focused as well try:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="text"]:focus   
{
         background: transparent;
         border: none;
         outline-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the opacity to 0. This made it disappear but still function when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should never completly remove the `outline` or `:focus` style.

https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines

> ...using `outline: none` without proper fallbacks makes your site significantly less accessible to any keyboard only user, not only those with reduced vision. Make sure to always give your interactive elements a visible indication of focus.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need the existence of it you could also throw it off the screen with `display: fixed; right: -1000px;`. It is useful when you need an input for copying to clipboard. :)