# How to make input element completely transparent?

Tags: html, css, transparency

How can I make the input element completely transparent so that it has the body background image and not the background colour of its parent?
HTML code:

```css
body{
    background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Neckertal_20150527-6384.jpg");
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add css as follows:

```
#wrapper > input {
     background-color: transparent;
     border: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the border on focus too, then add:

```
#wrapper > input:focus {
     outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way :

```css
#wrapper{
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
}

#wrapper > input
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Similar answer was posted few years ago : [set input transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351966/is-there-a-pure-css-way-to-make-an-input-transparent)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you are trying to prevent child element from inheriting parent's background color.

The only way to do is overriding the style

I don't know if this works for you but you can do:

```
input{
        background-image:url("image.jpg");
        border: none;
    }
```

you can also do whatever part of the background image you want to display instead input field, simply cut that part of the image and set as a background image for the input field.